# Need to open file in a "r" and "rb" mode in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, hash

Is it ok to open the same files within one context manager? (1)

```
with open(full_path, 'r') as s_stream, open(full_path, 'rb') as b_stream:
    rows = csv.DictReader(s_stream, delimiter=self.delimiter) # list of dicts
    print(sha256(b_stream.read()) #sha256 on bytes
```

I just need that original data checksum was equal to the checksum after reading it into Python program.The only thing that confuses me is what about handling very large files ca 10GB. Basically I need list of dicts (DictReader does it already) and at the same time be able to represent correct hash.

I have tried:

```
with open(full_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as s_stream:
    print(sha256(s_stream.read().encode('utf-8')) #sha256 on str that converted to bytes
```

And hash is not the same as in the (1) example. Hash at (1) is correct one.

I just want to be sure that opening the same file twice in case of correct hashing and getting data is OK.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file only in "rb" mode and decoding the `bytes` for the DictReader?

Comment: @scr seems that DictReader doesn't parse it correctly

Comment: I haven't tried it but each file object maintains its own read position into the file, so it should be ok. I just don't see any advantage to it versus opening it once for one task and then opening it again for the different task.